# Disposing a MailMessage attachment

Tags: c#, idisposable

Is it acceptable to do the following :

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(path, mediaType);

//Do other stuff...

using(attachment)
{
   //Send email
}
```

I usually create my disposable directly inside the using statement but in this case it's a bit complicated.

**Background**

I just encountered a bug in a legacy application where the email attachment is not releasing the file handle. So, the file can no longer be modified as it's already in use.

It seems the problem is that the programmer forgot to call Dispose() on the attachment. Usually, this would be an easy problem to solve, but in this case, because of the structure of the code, I can't easily put the attachment inside a using directly when it's created.

Is the alternative above a good compromise?

Comment: Isn't it easier just to call attachment.Dispose() at the end of the method?

Comment: So your question comes down to "will `using(attachment)` dispose `attachment` when leaving the `using`-block". Just put a breakpoint into `Dispose` and check if it´s called.

Comment: @TomasSmagurauskas If you think it's easier to ensure that none of that code will ever throw an exception (or otherwise alter the program's execution such that it doesn't call the last method in the method) under any circumstances...either now or ever in the future, then I guess.

Comment: @TomasSmagurauskas Yes, I guess. Problem is that calling Dispose() properly is not really easier. I need to wrap it inside a try finally to make it work properly. Sadly, between the attachment come from a series a 5 methods call before the email is actually sent so I will need to properly wrap each of those method with try catch in order to manage all the cases...

Comment: @HimBromBeere Of course the `using` statement will dispose it when control leaves the block; that is the whole point of that statement.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I never said anything against. I just encouraged the OP to investigate into it.

Comment: @Servy Why did you deleted useful information from the website? Seriously, way to waste everyone time here...

Comment: @Gudradain Answers to the question need to be posted as answers, not edited into the question.  The question is where you ask your question, not answer it.

Comment: @Servy And you closed said question so we can no longer answer it. While the answer I selected is perfectly valid for mail attachment, I wanted to point out that the same pattern can be used across a wide variety of situation like those.

Comment: @Gudradain And editing the question is not the appropriate way to go about doing that.  If you want to respond to an answer, you can post a comment under it.  Editing your question to provide feedback on an answer is not appropriate.  As to the closure, if you edit your question to fix the problems with it, such that it no longer merits closure, it can be reopened, and additional answers will be able to be posted.

Comment: @Servy Can I ask you an off-topic question? Why did you stop asking question on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Gudradain I never really started in the first place. I've only ever asked one question that I expected/wanted to get an answer for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The real issue is that you shouldn't need to Dispose the Attachment because the MailMessage will dispose of the attachment automatically when and IF you call Dispose on MailMessage.

```
using(MailMessage message = ...)
{

}
```

Looking at the internals of the MailMessage class, you'll see that an Attachment collection (attachments) is being disposed:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
        if (disposing && !disposed)
        {
            disposed = true;

            if(views != null){
                views.Dispose();
            }
            if(attachments != null){
                attachments.Dispose();
            }
            if(bodyView != null){
                bodyView.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailMessage.cs

Comment: That seems interesting.Does it mean I could do mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()) without any issue?

Comment: Looks like you are right! The class Attachment itself use the same pattern to dispose of the stream it contains.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurs during `//Do other stuff`, your object won't be disposed.

You could just use a more traditional try/finally:

```
Attachment attachment;
try
{
    attachment = new Attachment(path, mediaType);
    //Do other stuff...
}
catch
{
    //Handle or log exception
}
finally
{
    if (attachment != null) attachment.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I doubt OP can put the code into a try/finally-block when he/she isn´t able to put it into a `using`-block also.

Comment: In C# 6.0 and later, you can also say `finally { attachment?.Dispose(); }` is you are a fan of the `?.` operator.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Indeed, using the try finally is also complicated.